# Pros and cons of the various methods of plotting sql data

Tags: sql-server, database, plot

I am a mathematician/software developer and I when dealing with relational database data am always frustrated there isn't a seamless way to plot it. Now, I know that plotting data is possible. I can connect to a database with R or with python (using matplotlib) or write my own plotter in the language of my choice. There are probably many other ways to do it, e.g. I understand javascript has some decent plotting libraries and I would guess that are some nice guis that specialize in doing that but which I am just not aware of.

What are the pros and cons of the different routes for getting from a SQL query of data (not just what is already in a table) and turning it into a plot? I am open to suggestions.

I am currently using SQL Server data, though have used other databases in the past and expect to the future.

Comment: SQL Server stores and returns data. Plotting it visually is someone else's job (maybe reporting services, maybe the new Power BI stuff, but not SQL Server).

Comment: I agree that a databases job is storing data. But I still find myself frequently wanting plots of that data and wishing I had SSMS, only with lots of plotting options (lines plots, scatter plots with alpha, histograms,...)